# Combining scenario to Replace Medians by Groups in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, lapply

I have dataset

```
mydat <- 
structure(list(code = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("52382MCK", 
"52499MCK"), class = "factor"), item = c(11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 
11709L, 11708L, 11708L, 11708L, 11710L, 11710L, 11710L, 11710L, 
11710L, 11710L, 11710L, 11710L, 11710L, 11710L, 11710L, 11710L, 
11710L, 11710L, 11710L, 11710L, 11710L, 11710L, 11710L, 11710L, 
11710L, 11202L, 11203L, 11203L, 11204L, 11204L, 11205L, 11205L
), sales = c(30L, 10L, 20L, 15L, 2L, 10L, 3L, 30L, 10L, 20L, 
15L, 2L, 10L, 3L, 30L, 10L, 20L, 15L, 2L, 10L, 3L, 30L, 10L, 
20L, 15L, 2L, 10L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), action = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -35L), class = "data.frame")
# coerce to data.table
setDT(mydat)
```

with this dataset, several operations are performed.

```
1. selecting scenario by groups.
```

So there is action column. It can have only two values zero(0) or one(1).

The  scenarios are the number of zero categories of action before first category of action and the number of zeros after one category of action.

```
For example
52382МСК    11709
```

it is scenario when we have 1 zero category of action col. before first category of action col , and two zeros after first category of action col. Note: maybe scenario when we have 2 zero category of action col. before first category of action col , and 1 zero after first category of action col.

```
mydat1

code    item    sales   action
52382МСК    11709   30  0
52382МСК    11709   10  1
52382МСК    11709   20  0
52382МСК    11709   15  0
```

to detect this scenario i use this script/
This script very well works, thank for @Uwe

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

max_zeros <- 3
zeros <- sapply(0:max_zeros, stringr::str_dup, string = "0")
names(zeros) <- as.character(nchar(zeros))
sc <- CJ(zeros.before = zeros, zeros.after = zeros)[
  , scenario.name := paste(nchar(zeros.before), nchar(zeros.after), sep = "-")][
    , action.pattern := sprintf("%s1+(?=%s)", zeros.before, zeros.after)][]
# special case: all zero
sc0 <- data.table(
  zeros.before = NA,
  zeros.after = NA, 
  scenario.name = "no1", 
  action.pattern = "^0+$")
sc <- rbind(sc0, sc)
```

and then

```
setDT(mydat)
class <- mydat[, .(scenario.name = sc$scenario.name[
  paste(action, collapse = "") %>% 
    stringr::str_count(sc$action.pattern) %>%
    is_greater_than(0) %>% 
    which() %>% 
    max()
  ]),
  by = .(code, item)][]

class
mydat[class, on = .(code, item)]
```

So i get data with class of scenario.

```
2.operation it is replace median.
```

For each scenario median by zero category is calculated.

I need to calculate the median by 1 preceding zeros category by action column, i.e. which go before one category of action column, and by 2 zeros by action column that go after the one category. 
The median replacing performed only for first category of action column
 by sale column.
if median is more than the sales, then do not replace it.

To do it i use the script

```
sales_action <- function(DF, zeros_before, zeros_after) {
  library(data.table)
  library(magrittr)
  action_pattern <- 
    do.call(sprintf, 
            c(fmt = "%s1+(?=%s)", 
              stringr::str_dup("0", c(zeros_before, zeros_after)) %>% as.list()
            ))
  message("Action pattern used: ", action_pattern)
  setDT(DF)[, rn := .I]
  tmp <- DF[, paste(action, collapse = "") %>% 
              stringr::str_locate_all(action_pattern) %>% 
              as.data.table() %>% 
              lapply(function(x) rn[x]),
            by = .(code, item)][
              , end := end + zeros_after]
  DF[tmp, on = .(code, item, rn >= start, rn <= end), 
     med := as.double(median(sales[action == 0])), by = .EACHI][
       , output := as.double(sales)][action == 1, output := pmin(sales, med)][
         , c("rn", "med") := NULL][]
}
```

and then

```
sales_action(mydat, 1L, 2L)
```

so i get the result.

## the question is based on the following

Each time i must manually enter the scenario to replacing by median

```
sales_action(mydat, 1L, 2L)
sales_action(mydat, 3L, 1L)
sales_action(mydat, 2L, 2L)
```

and so on.

How to do that replacing median was perform for all possible scenarios automatically
so that I do not write every time
sales_action(mydat, .L, .L)

So example of output

```
code    i    tem    sales   action  output  pattern
52382MCK    11709   30        0       30    01+00
52382MCK    11709   10        1       10    01+00
52382MCK    11709   20        0       20    01+00
52382MCK    11709   15        0       15    01+00
52382MCK    1170    8         0        8    01+00
52382MCK    1170    10        1        8    01+00
52382MCK    1170    2         0        2    01+00
52382MCK    1170    15        0        15   01+00
```

Comment: I'm struggling to extract the critical bits of information from your post, as there is a lot of text/code here. It would help if you were to condense your post, make it more succinct, and only keep critically relevant parts of your code.

Comment: @MauritsEvers, yes, there is many information, cause this post is consequence of my previous, but Uwe helped me. Henceforth I will try to be brief

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If I understand correctly*, the OP wants to analyse the success of sales actions by comparing `sales` figures during actions with the median sales of the periods immediately before and after the sales action.

There are some challenges:

1. There might be more than one sales action per `code`, `item` group.
2. The available data might cover *less* than the requested 3 three days each before and after a sales action.

IMHO, the introduction of scenarios is a detour to handle issue 2.

The approach below

- identifies the sales actions within each `code`, `item` group,
- picks up to three zero action rows *before* and up to three rows *after* each sales action,
- computes the median sales of those rows, and
- updates `output` in case the sales figure within a sales action exceeds the median of the surrounding zero action rows.

The term *category* has been coined by the OP to distinguish between periods of sales actions (contiguous streaks of `action == 1L`) and the zero action periods before and after.

```
library(data.table)
# coerce to data.table and create categories
setDT(mydat)[, cat := rleid(action), by = .(code, item)][]

# extract action categories, identify preceeding & succeeding zero action categories
mycat <- mydat[, .(action = first(action)), by = .(code, item, cat = cat)][
  , `:=`(before = cat - 1L, after = cat + 1L)][action == 1L]

mycat

       code  item cat action before after
1: 52382MCK 11709   2      1      1     3
2: 52382MCK 11708   2      1      1     3
3: 52382MCK 11710   2      1      1     3
4: 52382MCK 11710   4      1      3     5
5: 52382MCK 11710   6      1      5     7
6: 52499MCK 11203   2      1      1     3
7: 52499MCK 11205   1      1      0     2
```

Note that group `52382MCK, 11710` includes three separate sales actions. `before` and `after` may point to non-existing `cat` but this will be rectified automatically during the subsequent joins.

```
# compute median of surrouding zero action categories
action_cat_median <- 
  rbind(
    # get sales from up to 3 zero action rows before action category
    mydat[mycat, on = .(code, item, cat = before), 
          .(sales = tail(sales, 3), i.cat), by =.EACHI],
    # get sales from up to 3 zero action rows after action category
    mydat[mycat, on = .(code, item, cat = after), 
          .(sales = head(sales, 3), i.cat), by =.EACHI]
  )[
    # remove empty groups
    !is.na(sales)][
      # compute median for each action category
      , .(med = as.double(median(sales))), by = .(code, item, cat = i.cat)]

action_cat_median
```

> ```
>        code  item cat  med
> 1: 52382MCK 11709   2 20.0
> 2: 52382MCK 11708   2  2.5
> 3: 52382MCK 11710   2 10.0
> 4: 52382MCK 11710   4 10.0
> 5: 52382MCK 11710   6 10.0
> 6: 52499MCK 11203   2  2.0
> ```

```
# prepare result
mydat[, output := as.double(sales)][
  # update join
  action_cat_median, on = .(code, item, cat), output := pmin(sales, med)]
```

**Edit:** Alternatively, the call to `pmin()` can be replaced by a *non-equi join* which updates only rows where sales exceeds the median:

```
# prepare result, alternative approach
mydat[, output := as.double(sales)][
  # non-equi update join
  action_cat_median, on = .(code, item, cat, output > med), output := med]


mydat
```

> ```
>         code  item sales action cat output
>  1: 52382MCK 11709    30      0   1   30.0
>  2: 52382MCK 11709    10      1   2   10.0
>  3: 52382MCK 11709    20      0   3   20.0
>  4: 52382MCK 11709    15      0   3   15.0
>  5: 52382MCK 11708     2      0   1    2.0
>  6: 52382MCK 11708    10      1   2    2.5
>  7: 52382MCK 11708     3      0   3    3.0
>  8: 52382MCK 11710    30      0   1   30.0
>  9: 52382MCK 11710    10      0   1   10.0
> 10: 52382MCK 11710    20      0   1   20.0
> 11: 52382MCK 11710    15      1   2   10.0
> 12: 52382MCK 11710     2      0   3    2.0
> 13: 52382MCK 11710    10      0   3   10.0
> 14: 52382MCK 11710     3      0   3    3.0
> 15: 52382MCK 11710    30      0   3   30.0
> 16: 52382MCK 11710    10      0   3   10.0
> 17: 52382MCK 11710    20      0   3   20.0
> 18: 52382MCK 11710    15      1   4   10.0
> 19: 52382MCK 11710     2      0   5    2.0
> 20: 52382MCK 11710    10      0   5   10.0
> 21: 52382MCK 11710     3      0   5    3.0
> 22: 52382MCK 11710    30      0   5   30.0
> 23: 52382MCK 11710    10      0   5   10.0
> 24: 52382MCK 11710    20      0   5   20.0
> 25: 52382MCK 11710    15      1   6   10.0
> 26: 52382MCK 11710     2      0   7    2.0
> 27: 52382MCK 11710    10      0   7   10.0
> 28: 52382MCK 11710     3      0   7    3.0
> 29: 52499MCK 11202     2      0   1    2.0
> 30: 52499MCK 11203     2      0   1    2.0
> 31: 52499MCK 11203     2      1   2    2.0
> 32: 52499MCK 11204     2      0   1    2.0
> 33: 52499MCK 11204     2      0   1    2.0
> 34: 52499MCK 11205     2      1   1    2.0
> 35: 52499MCK 11205     2      1   1    2.0
>         code  item sales action cat output
> ```

The following rows have been updated:

```
mydat[output != sales]
```

> ```
>        code  item sales action cat output
> 1: 52382MCK 11708    10      1   2    2.5
> 2: 52382MCK 11710    15      1   2   10.0
> 3: 52382MCK 11710    15      1   4   10.0
> 4: 52382MCK 11710    15      1   6   10.0
> ```

Comment: Very nice and clean code.  Some addition. How do I separate scenarios  3L - 3L in a separate data set? So it will two datasets 1. all scenarios without 3l3l and 2. dataset only with scenario 3l-3l

Comment: @D.Joe, thank you. Please, can you specify in more detail which rows are supposed to be moved to each subset, especially for edge cases? All rows of group `52382MCK, 11710` belong to the 3L-3L scenario (`000100000010000001000`). But what is about `00010001000`, `00001000000010000`, or `000100000010`, e.g.?

Comment: sorry, any troubles with my internet connection. Coudn't get web.  Now ok.What about your question. Thank you for your the deepest analytical skills, so i think, let's this strange cases, like you found, put in new separately dataset, and i will consider in sql what to do with these sales.  Is it possible to put the strange case in one separate dataset?

Comment: @D.Joe, I have upated my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51933156/3817004) to show how to split `mydat` into separate datasets for each scenario. If this is not matching your requirements I suggest to post a new question.

Comment: what about this string 'sales_action(mydat, 1L, 2L)' and string from this post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51899131/selecting-groups-by-its-scenario-in-r/51933156?noredirect=1#comment91648334_51933156  'split(mydat[class, on = .(code, item)], by = "scenario.name")'  IT IS ALL GOOD.  I just want to do that 'sales_action(mydat, 1L, 2L)' would work only for splitted datasets besides 3-3. Speaking as if R is a man  '' sales_action(mydat,split(mydat[class, on = .(code, item)], by = "scenario.name") where class is not 3-3) How to do it?

Comment: i tried do that sales_action(mydat,split(mydat[class, on = .((code, item)], by = "scenario.name"))   so the error.
 Show Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in stri_dup(string, times) : 
  argument "zeros_after" is missing, with no default  . Can't understand why.  also i want get  the csv spl=split(mydat[class, on = .(code, item)], by = "scenario.name") write.csv(spl,"spl.csv")

Comment: Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 8963070, 67964, 760177, 6555, 116607, 14414, 7541, 186296, 31448, 15382, 9374, 5605, 10269, 1596, 1884, 682. Is there the way to fix errors?

Comment: @D.Joe Function `sales action()` expects three parameters, but you have passed only two - that's what the error message *argument "zeros_after" is missing, with no default* says. And, the second parameter expects an integer value while you passed a list of data.tables (the result of `split()`)

Comment: @D.Joe Also, please, note that comments are not meant to ask additional questions which go beyond the scope of the underlying original question. I understand that you are tasked with a rather complex problem. Therefore, I kindly suggest to ask separate questions with a clear problem scope.